# Есть ли возможность оповестить людей о конференции / митапе?

Tags: поддержка, реклама

Коллеги, планируется **бесплатное** мероприятие от моего сообщества. К большому сожалению нигде нет информации о возможности прорекламировать / каким-либо образом осветить мероприятие.

Подскажите, есть ли возможность оповестить людей о конференции / митапе на Stack Overflow?

Comment: В чате можно создавать события.

Comment: Обновил ваш вопрос, сделав его каноническим. Пожалуйста, вносите правки при необходимости!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky благодарю

Comment: Предлагаю оставить вопрос в рамках обсуждения самой темы и в не рекламных целей. На мой взгляд, очень важно найти подход к проблеме в общем.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хорошо, как скажете.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а отвечать кто будет?

Comment: @Qwertiy Любой, кто знает ответ. Вы, например, можете ответить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, лично я ответа не знаю. Вроде как реклама на англоязычных сайтах поддерживается, и она бесплатна для open source. Если бесплатный митап расценивать таким же образом, то почему бы нет? И баннеры про сам ruSO у нас крутятся. Но ко всей этой схеме я не имею никакого отношения, так что ответить не могу.

Comment: Ну так то - вроде есть куча площадок для подобного. Группы профильные в ВК или чаты типа Gitter. Тут явно нет ЦА автора (точнее она есть, но явно не в 100%). Только если тег отдельный для такого плана тем делать.

Comment: Было бы круто иметь возможность размещать подобную рекламу в качестве вопросов на ruSO, люди имеющие подписки на метки сразу бы узнавали о мероприятии. Конечно я говорю о бесплатных митапах.